# Cannot merge Hash object with ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash object (class name Hash):

```
h1 = {
 :hot_products=>{:enabled=>true, :always_enable=>false, :order=>0},
 :recent_products=>{:enabled=>true, :always_enable=>true, :order=>1},
 :event_promotion=>{:enabled=>true, :always_enable=>false, :order=>2}
}
```

And I has a params object( class name ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess)

```
h2 = { 
 "hot_products"=>{"enabled"=>"1"},
 "recent_products"=>{"enabled"=>"0"},
 "event_promotion"=>{"enabled"=>"1"}
}
```

And I want to merge these object using deep_merge

`h1.deep_merge(h2)`

Then I got:

```
{
 :hot_products=>{:enabled=>true, :always_enable=>false, :order=>0},
 :recent_products=>{:enabled=>true, :always_enable=>true, :order=>1},
 :event_promotion=>{:enabled=>true, :always_enable=>false, :order=>2},
 "hot_products"=>{"enabled"=>"1"},
 "recent_products"=>{"enabled"=>"0"},
 "event_promotion"=>{"enabled"=>"1"}
}
```

Does anyone know how can I merge these two object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is `h1` has symbol keys and `h2` has string keys

Make `h1` as `HashWithIndifferentAccess`

```
h1 = {
 :hot_products=>{:enabled=>true, :always_enable=>false, :order=>0},
 :recent_products=>{:enabled=>true, :always_enable=>true, :order=>1},
 :event_promotion=>{:enabled=>true, :always_enable=>false, :order=>2}
}.with_indifferent_access
```

and

```
h2 = { 
 "hot_products"=>{"enabled"=>"1"},
 "recent_products"=>{"enabled"=>"0"},
 "event_promotion"=>{"enabled"=>"1"}
}
```

Now, you can `deep_merge` the hash and it will return you proper result

```
h1.deep_merge(h2)

{
 "hot_products"=>{"enabled"=>"1", "always_enable"=>false, "order"=>0},
 "recent_products"=>{"enabled"=>"0", "always_enable"=>true, "order"=>1}, 
 "event_promotion"=>{"enabled"=>"1", "always_enable"=>false, "order"=>2}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
h1=ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(h1)
h1.deep_merge(h2)
=> {"hot_products"=>{"enabled"=>"1", "always_enable"=>false, "order"=>0}, "recent_products"=>{"enabled"=>"0", "always_enable"=>true, "order"=>1}, "event_promotion"=>{"enabled"=>"1", "always_enable"=>false, "order"=>2}}
```